# ng-serve does not start server

Tags: angular

when I try to run the command `ng-serve` from a scaffolded Angular2 project(created with angular-cli), I get the following error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/client/tsconfig.json'

I read this [post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/402) and added a client folder in `src` and moved everything inside it. Now I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
>       at Angular2App._getTsTree`

Any idea whats going wrong ? I am using the newest angular-cli